# how to add the top three elements in array and delete the previous results in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

what i need

- i need to store the top 3 element in array .
- and remove previous top first three element from array.
- when 4 th elements adds up in array 1 is deleted , whn 5 th adds up 2 is deleted.
- max array limit is 3.
- like arr[1,2,3];
- when 4 th element inserted it will delete the arr[1] index and so on.
- and store the array in cookie

js code

```
   var cookie_event_id=document.getElementById("eventID").value;

    var e = $(window).height();

   var arr=[];
   if (cookie.get("event_id")) {
    var t=cookie_event_id;
    var t = cookie.get("event_id");
    console.log(arr.toString());

    arr.push(cookie_event_id);
    arr.shift(); 
    alert(cookie_event_id);

    var i = new Date;
    i.setDate(i.getFullYear() ), document.cookie = "event_id =" + cookie_event_id + ";expires=" + i.toUTCString() + ";domain=.10times.com;path=/"
} else
 {
    var t=cookie_event_id;
    var i = new Date;
    i.setDate(i.getFullYear() ), document.cookie = "event_id =" + t + ";expires=" + i.toUTCString() + ";domain=.10times.com;path=/"
}
```

- i want that id should get appended in array , then  that array should get pushed in cookie.
- and delete first index of array when new element adds up, and so on.
- max limit of arrays is 3.

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? I think [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) could be leveraged for most of your question, even though there's like 10 things you're asking how to do here.

Comment: Take these one at a time - start with slice/splice and come back when you have specific questions about one thing at a time - this is not a good syntax btw: `i.setDate(i.getFullYear() ), document.cookie ...` and why set the date to its own year? What is the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add new element at the beginning of array:
Use `unshift`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.unshift(4); // [4, 1, 2, 3]
arr.length = 3; // [4, 1, 2]
```

> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

If you want the element to added at the end:
Use `push` and `shift`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.push(4); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.shift(); // [2, 3, 4]
```

`push`:

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

`shift`:

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need to keep the three most recently added items:

```
myArray = [];

var addEItem = function(item) {
    myArray.push(item); // Add at the end of the array
    if (myArray.length > 3) {
        myArray.shift(); // Remove 1st item if size is larger than 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `array.splice()`. Here a little example:

```
var arr = ["el1", "el2", "el3","el4", "el6", "el7"];
console.log(arr.splice(3)); // ["el4", "el6", "el7"]
```

What you need is to push your result then splice it as show in the example above.
http://jsfiddle.net/ztvs2trt/

Comment: Sorry, I mean splice! :)

Answer (score 0):

updated  working code

```
 var cookie_event_id=document.getElementById("eventID").value;
 //alert(cookie_event_id);
var e = $(window).height();

 var arr=[];
if (cookie.get("event_id")) {

    var t = cookie.get("event_id") + ','+cookie_event_id;
   var arr = JSON.parse("[" + t+ "]");
    if(arr.length > 3)
    arr.shift(); 
    alert(arr);
    arr.toString();


    var i = new Date;
    i.setDate(i.getFullYear() ), document.cookie = "event_id =" + arr + ";expires=" + i.toUTCString() + ";domain=.10times.com;path=/"
} else
 {
    var t=cookie_event_id;
    var i = new Date;
    i.setDate(i.getFullYear() ), document.cookie = "event_id =" + t + ";expires=" + i.toUTCString() + ";domain=.10times.com;path=/"
}
```